# Crystal Reports with Arabic text alignment

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, crystal-reports

I'm using ASP.NET, Visual Studio 2013- SP4 with Crystal Reports v13.0.15 and I have problem of Arabic text alignment as follows:

> - Right and center aligned text always appear left aligned on printing, it is shown OK in browser and designer (I have tried
>     different printers:my Deskjet printer, Microsoft XPS writer and pdf
>     writer).
> - This problem is with Arabic text only, English text aligned well when printed.
> - I face this problem with TextObject  and with multiline FieldObject (or FieldObject with CanGrow set to true).
>     Exporting to pdf works well, I have problems with printing only (using the ActiveX Mode in CrystalReportViewer, IE11).

For example the following picture is browser view (everything is aligned Right, gray boxes are text objects):

[image]

while the printed version is as follows:

[image]

I appreciate any help. thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure: do you simply type in those fields (then probably having RTL marker) or you also set right-to-left property for those controls?

Comment: yes of course , every think is OK in browser or export PDF Just print

Answer (score 1):

This is due to use english word with arabic.
if only arabic text come it work good if english text come with arabic then it align automatically left.